# jQuery - Getting custom validation methods to trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

If I've added a custom validation method to my form, how can I get it to trigger prior to submit?

I'm not decorating my form fields but I thought that adding the new method to my rules section would trigger the method but it doesn't work.

```
$.validator.addMethod('myCustomValidation', function (data)
{
   // do some work here 
   return myValidationResult;

}, 'Please respond.');


$("#myFormId").validate({        
    rules: {
         "myCustomValidation": {required: true}
    },
    messages: {
       "myCustomValidation": {
           required: "Enter some information before proceeding",        
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form)
    {
        // do the work to submit this form
    }
});
```

I'd like have the validation get triggered when the 'submit' button is pressed.

However, if I add the validation class name to any form field except the submit button, this rule gets triggered. Just can't seem to get it to be triggered just prior to submit..

Comment: I think editting this to include the HTML snippet containing the form you're trying to validate will help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the `addMethod` function but I can suggest you this:

```
$.validator.methods.myCustomValidation = function(value, element, param) {
    // Perform custom validation and return true or false
    return value === '' || /^([0-9]{10})$/.test(value);
};


$("#myFormId").validate({        
    rules: {
        myElement: { 
            myCustomValidation: true 
        }
    },
    messages: {
        myElement: { 
            myCustomValidation: "Enter some information before proceeding" 
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form)
    {
        // do the work to submit this form
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. What I am trying to do is make sure the validation gets fired before the submitHandler is invoked. I thought having the rules on the element (specified in class name) would trigger the validation.. Perhaps I don't understand the docs all that well.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in:

```
$(function(){
   //your code goes here
});
```

this will attach validation events on-page-load.

Comment: It's already wrapped -- it's more that the validation doesn't get triggered prior to the form being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something. rules should look like this.

```
rules: {
    "elemId": {
        required: true,
        myCustomValidation: true
     }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `.valid()` to trigger the validation:

```
$("#myFormId").valid();
```

Comment: Can you call 'valid' inside the submitHandler?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for addClassRules

```
$.validator.addMethod('myCustomValidation', function (data)
{
   // do some work here 
   return myValidationResult;

}, 'Please respond.');

$.validator.addClassRules({
  myCustomValidation: { myCustomValidation: true, required: true }
});

$("#myFormId").validate({        
    messages: {
       "myCustomValidation": {
           required: "Enter some information before proceeding",        
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form)
    {
        // do the work to submit this form
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the native [$.validator.addMethod](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to bind the custom method.  After that, just call jquery's `blur()` on the `element` to trigger validation.

Due to a race condition that I suspect exists in jQuery Validate, I had to **spin wait** in order to avoid getting a blank error message when I programmatically invoke validation

```
            //after binding custom validation method
           if($("#myElement").length){//add any checks you need
                var millisecondsToWait = 500;
                //Spin because it works
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#myElement").blur();
                    //$("#myElement").valid();//or this
                }, millisecondsToWait);
```